# ejs templating engine with express 4, foreach fuction for object don't work

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I use ejs 1.0 and express 4 and i have problem with iteration. I try to use forEach for my object returned from database (mysql). This is my code for express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');
var db = require('./config/db.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));

var router = express.Router();

router.route('/todo')
    .post(function(req, res, next){
        db.query('INSERT INTO task SET todo_title = ?, todo_description =?',[req.body.title, req.body.description], function(err, info){
            if(err) {
                console.log('db error', err);
            }
            console.log('zadanie dodano z id: ');
            res.redirect('/api/todo');
        });

    }).get(function(req, res, next){
        db.query('SELECT todo_id, todo_description, data FROM task', function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        var data = JSON.stringify(result);
        res.render('pages/index', {items: data});
        });
    });

router.route('todo/:todo_id')
    .get(function(req, res){

    }).post(function(req, res){

    }).delete(function(req, res){
    });

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(3000);
```

and template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <section id="main">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <ul>
            <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
                <li><% item.todo_id %></li>
            <% }); %>
        </ul>
        <form action="/api/todo" method="POST">
            <label for="title">Nazwa zadania</lablel><br>
            <input name="title" type="text"><br>
            <label for="description">Opis zadania</label><br>
            <textarea name="description"></textarea><br>
            <button>Wyślij</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I try also for() but its don't work to. My object returned from get route:

```
[{"todo_id":1,"todo_description":"cos2","data":"2014-10-22T13:02:53.000Z"},{"todo_id":2,"todo_description":"cos2","data":"2014-10-22T13:03:13.000Z"},{"todo_id":3,"todo_description":"cos2","data":"2014-10-22T13:05:00.000Z"},{"todo_id":4,"todo_description":"cos2","data":"2014-10-22T13:06:03.000Z"},{"todo_id":5,"todo_description":"cos2","data":"2014-10-22T13:13:31.000Z"},{"todo_id":6,"todo_description":"asd","data":"2014-10-22T13:15:39.000Z"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely with the use of `stringify()`:

```
db.query('SELECT todo_id, todo_description, data FROM task', function(err, result){
    // ...
    var data = JSON.stringify(result);
    res.render('pages/index', {items: data});
});
```

String values, as `stringify()` creates, don't have a `.forEach()` method. And, `res.render()` and EJS don't require values to be JSON-encoded.

You can just assign `result`, an `Array` of `Object`s, to `items` without involving `JSON`:

```
res.render('pages/index', { items: result });
```

---

Or, you would need to `parse()` it within the view:

```
<% JSON.parse(items).forEach(function(item) { %>
```